# Como retornar um int em uma propriedade Decimal

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

Possuo uma string SQL (feito por outro programador a muito tempo atrás, logo, não posso mudá-lo) que retorna algo assim: Se tiver valor na coluna, retorna o valor, senão, retorna 0 (eu postaria aqui o SQL mas é gigantesco).

Porém, coluna com valor é decimal, sem o valor é inteiro. Pra passá-lo pro C#, eu criei uma model com a propriedade do tipo dynamic:

```
public dynamic valorRetornado { get; set; }
```

Porém ela vem nula. Tentei com object e também não funfou.

Alguém tem alguma ideia?

@HarryPotter aqui está:

```
//Data é a string aonde está o SQL
var dados = db.Database.SqlQuery<Produtos>(data);
                    foreach (var itens in dados)
                    {                        
                        listaProdutos.Add(customer);
                    }
```

Comment: Junior você poderia postar o código C# que resgata tal SQL ?

Comment: já vou colocar um exemplo de como eu faria !!! wait minutes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Então você deve colocar assim:

```
public Decimal valorRetornado { get; set; }
```

pelo fato que percebi que ta usando um [EntityFramework](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/) para gerar os dados.

Outro coisa se você for retornar **0** (*Zero*) mas, essa coluna pode conter valores *NULL* faça assim:

```
public Decimal? valorRetornado { get; set; }
```

e deixe retorna *NULL*, aonde não possui valor.

***Vamos com um exemplo simples***

Tenho em minha base de dados um tabela com essas caracteristicas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas, eu quero pegar 3 campos `Id`, `Nome` e `Valor` e criar uma classe no meu sistema para isso utilizando Entity Framework para executar uma SQL e trazer esses dados:

***Class Modelo***

```
public class Exemplo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public decimal? Valor { get; set; }
}
```

Nessa classe o campo Valor pode conter valores `Null`, igual a configuração padrão na minha base de dados, que automaticamente o *EntityFramework* vai tratar isso.

***Codificação:***

```
IList<Exemplo> exemplos = db
              .Database
              .SqlQuery<Exemplo>("SELECT Id, Nome, Valor FROM Exemplos")
              .ToList<Exemplo>();
```

*Atente que o nome do campo da tabela e seu tipo deve corresponder a sua classe para que não tenha problemas e erros de conversão*

***Dados contidos***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

***Dados trazidos, via Debug Visual Studio para a classe modelo criada***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Perceba que possui 3 itens, e o **Id** de número **2** o Valor está NULL igual da sua base de dados.

Comment: Eu nunca tinha sacado muito bem essa história (como/pra quê? utilizar) do `?` ao lado do tipo, show de bola! +1 pra vocêê! Valeuu!

Comment: @HarryPotter eu fiz como voce disse mas dá esse erro: The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Int32' type to the 'System.Decimal' type is not valid

Comment: @JuniorDias o seu problema talvez seja também na SQL se você jogar 0 faça um cast então para decimal, mas, na classe que recebe os dados ele não pode um campo dinâmico e sim um tipo primitivo, é mais tranquilo o trabalho de codificação. O meu exemplo acima comprova isso... de uma olhada!

Comment: @HarryPotter Muito obrigado pelos exemplos!

Answer (score 1):

Você não pode tratar tudo para `decimal`?? é bem perigoso utilizar o tipo `dynamic`, se você acabar esquecendo de algum tratamento vai ter exceptions...

Não sei como você está fazendo para ler do banco se é com `DataRow` ou com o `EntityFramework`, mas aqui vai uma ajuda...

`(!dr.IsNull("coluna") ? Convert.ToDecimal(dr["coluna"]) : 0.0m)`

Comment: se eu fazer com Entity, como posso converter?